# How can an MLP be implemented with convolutional layers?

Tags: keras, pytorch, feedforward-neural-networks, multilayer-perceptrons

I am studying the architecture of the network *pointnet*, specifically the MLPs stages of the pipeline highlighted in red in the following image (taken from the author page [here](http://stanford.edu/%7Erqi/pointnet/)):

[image: pointnet architecture]

It is strange to find out that this part was implemented with 2d convolutional layers by the authors, here is the snippet where they create the MLP(64,64) part ([here you'll find the complete code base](https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet/blob/master/models/pointnet_cls.py)):

```
 net = tf_util.conv2d(input_image, 64, [1,3],
                     padding='VALID', stride=[1,1],
                     bn=True, is_training=is_training,
                     scope='conv1', bn_decay=bn_decay)
net = tf_util.conv2d(net, 64, [1,1],
                     padding='VALID', stride=[1,1],
                     bn=True, is_training=is_training,
                     scope='conv2', bn_decay=bn_decay)
```

Same thing happened when I looked into the pytorch implementation, but now with 1d convolutional layers! ([code base here](https://github.com/fxia22/pointnet.pytorch/blob/master/pointnet/model.py)):

```
 self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv1d(k, 64, 1)
    self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv1d(64, 128, 1)
    self.conv3 = torch.nn.Conv1d(128, 1024, 1)
```

The extent of my knowledge is that MLPs are densely connected networks ([MLP definition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk)), even more so, in [this application of pointnet](https://www.mdpi.com/1999-4907/12/2/131) the authors depict the MLP stages as fully connected networks:

[image]

I am lost here, for what I can gather from the images there should be a dedicated MLP to transform every point independently, how does convolution help in this situation? Your insight will be greatly appreciated.

ERRDATA

I have just figured that the kernel size in the original tensorflow implementation is [1,3], meaning, that is also a 1D convolution, are they feeding the convolution of the three channels to the MLP?

Regards